# Comparing versions of a java project

Tags: java, eclipse

My developer sent me the source code to the new version of an application that he updated for me.  Is it possible for me to compare the source code from a previous version with this one to see what changes were made?  I'm using Eclipse and OSX.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`man diff`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff)

Comment: You can also use _FileMerge_, which comes bundled with Xcode on Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the future, you should look into using a version control system, like SVN (SmartSVN, TortoiseSVN, etc. etc...) This usually has an integrated tool to see differences from one version to the next. For now, something like BeyondCompare, WinDiff, UNIX command line `diff`, etc.

Comment: This begs an important question: "_is the project under version control?_" If it is, the OP probably wouldn't be asking the question...

Comment: Which is why I am suggesting he consider it in the future

Answer (score 0):

For comparing two files (or folders) on Eclipse, select both files (or folders), right click on any of them, and select `Compare With` option from the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "diff tool" to generate a nicely readable report of differences for you. See some examples here: http://www.git-tower.com/blog/diff-tools-mac/